# SQL Server : complex query to get average time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a complex SQL query please resolve. Here is the details of it.

[image]

As I think the screenshot I have attached shows all the requirements. The system works like this.

I am creating a text file in my application and logging the same in SQL Server also. As soon as this file gets created, with same name another file gets created with .html extension. I am logging the html file also in SQL Server. So basically if you want you can group the rows on the basis of file name to get a single request.

Now by using SQL I want to get the time difference between these two files. As you can see in the image that first request has taken 547 milliseconnds.

The same way I want to get the average time taken by all the requests in a minute or hour.

SQL Script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DebugInfo](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DebugInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ON
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (1, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000001.txt', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 511', CAST(0x0000A43300CF83FD AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (2, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000001.htm', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 335', CAST(0x0000A43300CF84A1 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (3, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000002.txt', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 672', CAST(0x0000A43300D0072D AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (4, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000002.htm', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 1006', CAST(0x0000A43300D00895 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (5, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000003.txt', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 254', CAST(0x0000A43300D00FC9 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (6, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000003.htm', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 136', CAST(0x0000A43300D01001 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (7, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000004.txt', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 772', CAST(0x0000A43300D0167E AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (8, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000004.htm', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 181', CAST(0x0000A43300D016C5 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (9, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000005.txt', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 347', CAST(0x0000A43300D01B65 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (10, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000005.htm', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 117', CAST(0x0000A43300D01B8F AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (11, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000006.txt', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 572', CAST(0x0000A43300F13506 AS DateTime), NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[DebugInfo] ([Id], [FileName], [Message], [Time], [UserId]) VALUES (12, N'\\172.16.1.18\datadrive\vol2\SCANNING\SCAN\NovToWin\SIP1\WH000006.htm', N'File Is LOCKED Count:- 562', CAST(0x0000A43300F13632 AS DateTime), NULL)
```

Here is what i have used to generate the RawFileName

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING((REVERSE
(
    SUBSTRING
    (
        REVERSE(FileName),0,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(FileName))
    )
)),0, CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE
(
    SUBSTRING
    (
        REVERSE(FileName),0,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(FileName))
    )
))) AS RawFileName from DebugInfo
```

Thanks

Comment: Too small text, I can't read it. Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay - You are not supposed to add sample data as image.. Always add sample data and expected result as text in table format

Comment: Is there some reason the `AVG` function didn't work for you?   How did you try it, and what error did you get?

Comment: I know guys.. you all are talented.  But please consider once before down voting.

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
select avg(diff_ms * 1.0)
from (select datediff(millisecond, min(time), max(time)) as diff_ms
      from t
      group by rawfilename
     ) t;
```

Comment: You query returns. Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: have you checked your query mate?

Answer (score 1):

```
select avg(diff) 
from ( select filename, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, Time, nextTime) as diff 
       from ( select [FileName] 
                   , [Time] 
                   , lead(Time, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS nextTime 
                   , row_number() over (partition by FileName order by Time) as rn
              from [DebugInfo] 
            ) tt
        where tt.rn = 1
      ) ttt

select avg(diff) 
from ( select datediff(millisecond, minTime, maxTime) as diff
        from ( select min(time) as minTime, max(time) ss maxTime
               from [DebugInfo]
               group by rawfilename
             ) tt
     ) ttt;
```

Comment: lead function does not work in SQL 2008 :(, also the second query returns "The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart." when i run the same on 1.5 lack rows.

Comment: @AbhishekK.Upadhyay Then use less precision

Comment: selected this answer because i wanted the query in sql2008. After a little change the query is working fine for me.

Comment: don't understand why people are down voting the question. And for a wrong answer they are up voting :)